# Tkinter updating label after using pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

When I run the .py file, the program runs fine as in self.error updates as robocopy is running. However after I've changed it to a .exe file using `pyinstaller -F -w Shortcutsv2.1.py` I've noticed that the tkinter label which shows how many files it has updated (self.error) doesn't update until after the terminal is closed. Is there a way to have it work like the script? I'm assuming this is due to a setting in pyinstaller but I may be wrong

**CODE:**

```
from subprocess import PIPE, run
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox as mb
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from os import path
from os import listdir
from os import mkdir
from os import walk
from glob import glob
import threading
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

class Windows(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, master):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 150
        master.geometry(f"{self.width}x{self.height}")
        master.title("Shortcuts")
        #master.iconbitmap(r'ip.ico')
        self.frame = tk.Frame(master,bg="white")
        self.frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        self.font = ('Helvetica', '10')

        #Source path label and text entry
        self.srcLabel = tk.Label(self.frame, text="Source Path:", font=self.font, bg="white")
        self.srcLabel.place(relx=0.001, rely=0.026, relwidth=0.31, relheight=0.2)
        self.srcEntry = tk.Entry(self.frame, font=self.font, bg="white")
        self.srcEntry.place(relx=0.31, rely=0.026, relwidth=0.68, relheight=0.2)

        #Destination path label and text entry
        self.dstLabel = tk.Label(self.frame, text="Destination Path:", font=self.font, bg="white")
        self.dstLabel.place(relx=0.001, rely=0.246, relwidth=0.31, relheight=0.2)
        self.dstEntry = tk.Entry(self.frame, font=self.font, bg="white")
        self.dstEntry.place(relx=0.31, rely=0.246, relwidth=0.68, relheight=0.2)

        #New Folder to be created label and text entry
        self.nfLabel = tk.Label(self.frame, text="New Folder:", font=self.font, bg="white")
        self.nfLabel.place(relx=0.001, rely=0.466, relwidth=0.31, relheight=0.2)
        self.nfEntry = tk.Entry(self.frame, font=self.font, bg="white")
        self.nfEntry.place(relx=0.31, rely=0.466, relwidth=0.68, relheight=0.2)

        #Submit
        self.submit = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Submit", bg="white", font=self.font,
                                command = self.threadCmd)
        self.submit.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.733, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.2)

        #Errors
        self.error = tk.Label(self.frame, text="", font=self.font, bg="white", fg="red")
        self.error.place(relx=0.001, rely=0.733, relwidth=0.53, relheight=0.2)

    def findFile(self, dirPath):
        #finds the full path of all files including within the subdirectories
        i = 0
        temp = []
        filesInDir = [f"{dirPath}\\{a}" for a in listdir(dirPath)]
        for a in filesInDir:
            i += 1
            fullPath = path.join(dirPath, a)
            if path.isdir(fullPath):
                temp = temp + self.findFile(fullPath)
            else:
                temp.append(fullPath)
        return temp

    def lowestFolder(self, direc):
        #finds the lowest last folder if any and creates the ~~~~.txt in there to ensure it is the last file to be copied
        subdir = [x[0] for x in walk(direc)]
        subdir.sort()
        if subdir[-1] == direc:
            f = open(path.join(direc,"~~~~.txt"),"w+")
            f.close()
        else:
            self.lowestFolder(str(path.join(direc,subdir[-1])))

    def Run(self):
        if not path.exists(self.srcEntry.get()):
            self.error.config(text="Can't find src path", fg="red")
        elif not path.exists(self.dstEntry.get()):
            self.error.config(text="Can't find dstn path", fg="red")
        else:
            dest = self.dstEntry.get() + "\\" + self.nfEntry.get()
            if path.isdir(dest):
                self.error.config(text="Folder Exists", fg="red")
            else:
                self.error.config(text="")
                self.filename = "logs.xlsx"
                self.listOfFiles = glob(path.join(".",self.filename))

                self.lowestFolder(self.srcEntry.get())

                filesTransferred = self.findFile(self.srcEntry.get())
                length = len(filesTransferred)
                mkdir(dest)
                date = datetime.now()

                run(f"start cmd /K RoboCopy.exe \"{self.srcEntry.get()}\" \"{dest}\" *.* /E /Z", stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)

                #Checks if all files have been transferred before moving on
                i = 0
                while(i < length):
                    fullPath = filesTransferred[i].replace(self.srcEntry.get(), dest)
                    if path.exists(fullPath):
                            i += 1
                    self.error.config(text=f'Transferring file(s): {i}/{length}', fg='black')

                temp2 = self.findFile(dest)
                temp2 = [x.replace(dest, "..") for x in temp2]

                if length == len(temp2):
                    #Creates log file if not created
                    if not self.listOfFiles:
                            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(self.filename, engine='xlsxwriter')
                            writer.save()

                    df = pd.read_excel(self.filename)

                    #creates file if it doesn't exist else apppends

                    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Started" : [date],
                                        "Source": [self.srcEntry.get()],
                                        "Destination": [self.dstEntry.get()],
                                        "Files": [", ".join(temp2)]})
                    df = df.append(df2, sort=False)
                    df.to_excel(self.filename, index=False)
                    self.error.config(text="Files copied successfully.", fg="green")
                    #IF ROBOCOPY FREEZES WHEN YOU CLICK ON IT THEN JUST PRESS TAB AND IT SHOULD RESUME
                else:
                    self.error.config(text="All files were not copied.", fg="red")

    def threadCmd(self):
        self.result = None
        y = threading.Thread(target=self.Run)
        y.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    x = threading.Thread(target=Windows, args=(root,))
    x.start()
    x.join
    root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT 1**

"*There are couple problems here. 1. Inherit class Windows(threading.Thread): but don't use this object. 2. Passing a class definition as .Thread(target=Windows. 3. Useless x.join without calling it. 4. Accessing tkinter objects, e.g.self.srcEntry.get(), from a Thread.*"

I've changed the code to the below so now:
1) Can't make this change as I'm using .start()
2) Changed this to an instance
3) called the function
4) Didn't make this change as wasn't sure what the issue was. Needs more clarification

The issue which I had posted for still persists however I appreciate the help to tidy up my code :)

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    x = Windows(root)
    x.start()
    x.join()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ***"When I run the `.py` file, the program runs fine"***: Can't belive that? There are couple problems here. **1.** Inherit `class Windows(threading.Thread):` but don't use this object. **2.** Passing a `class definition` as `.Thread(target=Windows`. **3.** Useless  `x.join` without calling it. **4.** Accessing `tkinter` objects, e.g.`self.srcEntry.get()`, from a `Thread`.

Comment: @stovfl Responded in Edit 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using `subprocess.run` instead of `subprocess.Popen`, `subprocess.run` waits for the terminal command to complete before moving on with the script. Whereas `subprocess.Popen` doesn't.

Edit: What I find strange is that when I would run it as a .py file `subprocess.run` worked the same as `subprocess.Popen` however when I had used pyinstaller then `subprocess.run` worked how it's supposed to.

Comment: Please select this as the correct answer. - the tick underneath the voting buttons.

Comment: Have to wait 2 days before I can. I will do so tomorrow :)